# Get the image data using the binary get

Tags: java, websocket, binary-image

Hi I have a task which i am not clear what to do may be I can get some suggestion to complete my task.

I have a image ID using that image ID I need to get a image data using binary get As I am not sure what this binary get mean may be it related to MessageBufferPacker and MessageUnpacker I believe and it is a task related to websocket

```
String id = String.valueOf(entity.get("id"));
//TODO   get the image data using the binary get
```

This is what I have very minimum detail, sorry if question is not clear just a try if i can get some help regarding this.

Comment: what do you want to do this image data?

Comment: Later I need to save it to different place using this image data

Comment: You should give more context. Is your program the client or the server? Do you really know, that this is related to web sockets? Do you want to retrieve the image data out of a database or do you want to call a web service? What should we do with this line of code? It could be everything. If you really don't know more context, you should ask your instructor/boss for clarification.

Comment: Yes it is related to web socket. My program is a server. Need to retrieve image out of data.

Comment: `As I am not sure what this binary get mean` me neither

Comment: Btw, thanks or the response guys will try to get more get all answer for my queries from my instructor.